# A person of mass 80kg is standing in a lift of mass 600kg.

Tags: classical-mechanics

The lift is supported by a cable which is modelled as light and inextensible. The lift is moving upwards and decelerating at 1.8m.s⁻²

a) Find the tension in the lift cable.
b) Find the magnitude of the normal reaction exerted by the floor of
the lift on the person.

I have attempted this question, and got very close answers to the mark scheme, but I can't figure out why my answer is different.

The correct answers are:

(a)  5576 N (5 marks)
(b)  656 N (4 marks)

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPgGA.png)

Comment: PhysicsSE maybe ?

Comment: @SagarM This kind of standard school exercise / homework is [explicitly off-topic there](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

The so-called correct answers seem to be obtained by taking the acceleration of gravity to be 10 m/sec$^2$ instead of 9.8 m/sec$^2$.